# Accessing a large number of unsorted array elements in Python

Tags: python, r, sparse-matrix, large-data, bigdata

I'm not very skilled in Python. However, I'm pretty handy with R. Yet, I do have to use Python since it has an up-to-date interface with Cplex. I'm also trying to avoid all the extra coding I would have to do in C/C++

That being said, I have issues with speed and efficiency on large lists/arrays/matrices...

I quickly wrote two lines in R, which are pretty ugly but work somewhat well...

```
doses = sapply(organSets[[2]], function(x) sum(voxMap_beamlet_val[which(voxMap_beamlet_iInd[,1] == x),1]))
length(which(doses <= sum(doses)/length(organSets[[2]])))/length(doses)
```

... these lines execute in about 5 minutes for `length(organSets[[2]])=52960` and `length(voxMap_beamlet_val) = length(voxMap_beamlet_iInd) = 1217077`

However, in Python, something similar takes about two hours. By using scipy.sparse, the execution time gets reduced by half, to about an hour... which is still obviously unacceptable...

Python code as follows...

```
voxMapBeamlet = sparse.coo_matrix((voxMap_beamlet_val,(voxMap_beamlet_iInd,voxMap_beamlet_jInd)),shape=(1055736,8500))
def getDose(voxInd):
    return sum([x.sum() for x in voxMapBeamlet.getrow(voxInd)])

def probDoseLevel2(orgVox,level=None):
    voxDose2 = [0] * len(orgVox)
    for i,v in enumerate(orgVox):
        voxDose2[i] = getDose(v)
    if level == None:
        level = sum(voxDose2)/len(orgVox)
    print len([x for x in voxDose2 if x <= level])/len(orgVox)

probDoseLevel2(organSets[1])
```

Please advise.

Comment: 1. This belongs on Code Review. 2. Try replacing `sum([x for x in voxDose2])` with `sum(voxDose2)` for a start.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I made the change, but testing on a smaller example there is no noticeable performance increase

Comment: If `level` isn't `None`, is `voxDose2` used for anything?

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want efficient access to rows, and COO format doesn't do that. Convert your `voxMapBeamlet` to Compressed Sparse Row format, and `getrow` becomes much more efficient:

```
voxMapBeamlet = sparse.coo_matrix((voxMap_beamlet_val,(voxMap_beamlet_iInd,voxMap_beamlet_jInd)),shape=(1055736,8500))
voxMapBeamlet = voxMapBeamlet.tocsr()
```

Second, `getDose` is a lot more complicated than it needs to be:

```
def getDose(voxInd):
    return voxMapBeamlet.getrow(voxInd).sum()
```

I suspect this will already be fast enough, but we should be able to push it further. We can push more of the work out of Python bytecode and into C-level routines using broadcasting and advanced indexing:

```
def probDoseLevel2(orgVox,level=None):
    relevantRows = voxMapBeamlet[orgVox]

    # Dense column matrix of row sums
    voxDose2 = relevantRows.sum(axis=1)
    if level is None:
        level = voxDose2.sum()/len(orgVox)
    return (voxDose2 <= level).sum() / len(orgVox)
```

Finally, if you're on Python 2, the division in your last line is integer division. That'll always produce 0 or 1 here, since `len(orgVox)` is at least as big as the numerator. There may be a similar problem with the division to produce `level`, depending on the dtype of the data you're working with. To turn on true division, you can put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that `return (voxDose2 <= level).sum() / len(orgVox)` doesn't yield what it needs to... `(voxDose2 <= level).sum()` gives me a count instead of the sum of values since `(voxDose2 <= level)` is a boolean matrix

Comment: @Constantine: Does it do the wrong thing? Summing a boolean matrix should produce a count of the number of Trues, since it automatically converts to an integer dtype for the summation.

Comment: `voxDoses[voxDoses <= level].sum()` produces the desired outcome... but I very much appreciate your post and comments. I think it was just a misunderstanding as to my intentions. I would not have been able to achieve the desired result without your help.

Comment: @Constantine: Wait, in `len([x for x in voxDose2 if x <= level])`, did you mean to call `len` or `sum`?

Comment: Sorry, I entangled myself... it's both.
The final line is `return voxDoses[voxDoses <= level].sum()/(voxDoses <= level).sum() / ((voxDoses <= level).sum()/len(orgVox))`

Comment: The issue was that I wasn't copy pasting everything I have and I was confusing what I had pasted with what I was trying to get answered and what my final goal is...